# How to generate sequential numbers on a web page?

Tags: html

Most of our staff work remotely in different countries of the world.

Often several staff work (on different aspects) of the same case.

At the moment the person who initiates the cases has to email the office manager who has to inssue a case number which then has to be shared with different staff members to make sure they use the same Case number in their forms and correspondence.

I was wondering whether it would be possible to:

1. Have a page on our website (accesible to our staff only)
2. Where the person initating a case goes to
3. The staff member is asked to enter his initials (eg DH or RD)
4. Then automatically a code is generated (RD001, DH001, etc.), it will be helpful for other purposes if the number is always 5 characters long (e.g. RD001, RD025, RD234, etc...).
5. These numbers need to be sequential (so if RD got the number RD001 1 hr ago, or 1 day ago, he needs to get RD002 the next time he requests a number), so the page needs to remember the last number that was issued for that staff member (they need to be sequential per staff member).
6. That number is then emailed to the relevant staff members who need to be aware that this number has been issued

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Sure it's possible, but what you are asking is actually a complete solution development. You've to hire a developer, who will create a system with authentication AND authorization, cases management (new case, details of the case, etc...) and so on.

But overall, it's a trivial job : )

- EDIT: If your question is exclusively considering only HTML, then I really don't think this is possible, since your "number" should be generated and accessed from anywhere. Then, you have to make it globally accessible.
  Also, it's really important that only your staff, and only the ones with rights to do that, could access and/or generate new numbers, hence the authorization/authentication need.
- EDIT 2: Another possibility is search for a already made solution. I believe that should exist even online services with your requirements, like some online CRM or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for an answer.

I am only looking to generate a number. The actual case details and everything else is not held online anywhere.

So even if someone unauthorized accesses that page, they will see nothing but an input field to enter their initials and 5 character code if they do so. There will be no references to the purpose of the codes or anything else but the code itself.

Comment: @Herwin . I understand what are you saying about security (or the no need of it), but even so, you'll need a centralized way to store and access it. At the very least you would need a counter. So it cannot be just plain `html` since it is static. You could even source this number with plain html, but to count (increment actually) and save it, you do really need a backend.